# i have a error with Notepad in QT

Tags: qt

when i use this function to show text

```
ui->plainTextEdit_2->appendPlainText()
```

the text look like that:

```
**** the starting point : axis.x = 400  axis.y =220
the pipline length :12
****  turnleft point :   axis.x = 388   axis.y = 220
Error points number 1:   distance from begin point:6
the pipe length:17
****  turnright point :   axis.x = 388   axis.y = 203
Error points number 1:   distance from begin point:11
```

but when i want to save file and use

```
    void MainWindow::on_actionSave_Text_triggered()
    {
    QString file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Open file name");
    QFile sFile(mFilename);
    if (!file.isEmpty()){
        mFilename = file;
        if(sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly)| QFile::Text){
            QTextStream out(&sFile);
            out<< temp;
            sFile.flush();
            sFile.close();
        }

    }
}
```

And when i open the file i save. the text show in different way like that(without down line)

```
**** the starting point : axis.x = 400  axis.y =220the pipline length :6****  turnleft point :   axis.x = 394   axis.y = 220Error points number 1:   distance from begin point:13the pipe length:23****  turnright point :   axis.x = 394  axis.y = 197the pipe length:23****  turnright point :   axis.x = 371   axis.y = 197Error points number 1:   distance from begin point:23
what should i  do to save the file and text appear in this file have structure like that:
**** the starting point : axis.x = 400  axis.y =220
the pipline length :12
****  turnleft point :   axis.x = 388   axis.y = 220
Error points number 1:   distance from begin point:6
the pipe length:17
****  turnright point :   axis.x = 388   axis.y = 203
Error points number 1:   distance from begin point:11
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're on Windows. My guess is the file is being saved in binary mode, and so Qt is not translating the "\n" characters into "\r\n".

You've got the QFile::Text modifier you need, but it's not in the right place.  You need to add that inside the open() function call parenthesis along with QFile::WriteOnly, like so:

```
if(sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your 'save' function blew my mind.

1. Why 'Open file name', when you actually save file?
2. Why don't you use `QString file` to save your data? What is `mFilename`? Or you think in this line `mFilename = file;` you also change the name of `sFile`? Well, you don't. You need t call `sFile.setFileName(file);` instead.
3. And what is `temp`?? Why not write `out << ui->plainTextEdit_2->toPlainText()`?

Second of all - `Qt` uses '\n' as line separator, while `Windows Notepad` uses '\r\n' and doesn't understand `\n`. So you'll have to use normal text editor (any other, I used, understood both ways correctly), or write conversion '\n' <-> '\r\n' when saving/loading:

```
QString text = ui->plainTextEdit_2->toPlainText();
text.replace('\n', "\r\n");
out << text;

...

// when loading:
QString text;
in >> text;
text.replace("\r\n", "\n");
ui->plainTextEdit_2->setPlainText(text);
```

**Update:**

darron's way with `QFile::Text` is better.